# Invoking Method when Parmaeter is instance of another class - Java

Tags: java, reflection

Ill try to make it short. 
I want to iterate through the methods of a class via "getMethods()". Now when the method has a Parameter which is an instance of the "Event" class, it should be invoked.

Example Method:

```
private void onEvent(ExampleEvent event) {...]
```

"ExampleEvent" is an instance of the "Event" class.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: "*Ill try to make it short.*" - You seem to have overdone it. What is your exact problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried getting the Parameters with "getParameters()" but I cant seem to find a way of getting the class of the Parameter.

Comment: As [@tripp-kinetics said in hers/his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697549/4216641), you should use [`Method#getParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes--), which will return a [`Class[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). From there on, you can use [`Class#isAssignableFrom(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) etc. to check your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `getParameterTypes()` instead of `getParameters()`.  If you want to match a parameter type to a parameter name, simply index the two arrays the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something Like this, its been awhile since i wrote in java but This something like this should work

Method[] methods = Class.getMethods();
    List<Method> methodsWithEvent = new List<Method>();
    for(Method method : methods){
       Class[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
       for(Class class : params)
          if(typeof(class) == typeof(ExampleEvent))
              methodsWithEvents.add(method);

    }
```